# how to fix the problem that a menu which is added to an existing menu doesn't be shown

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

i have develop a custom module which add a new menu in the attendance module to create attendance modification request for both groups "attendance/manual attendance" and "attendance/manager" the problem is my menu is added only for the admin user . If i connect with a user that has the access right manager or manual attendance for the attendance module  it will be not shown. Any idea for help ? 
Here is my code 
hr_attendance_modification_request_view.xml

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_attendance_modification_request_form">
    <field name="name">attendance.modification.request.form</field>
    <field name="model">attendance.modification.request</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Attendance modification Request">
            <header>
                <field name="state" statusbar_visible="draft,waiting,approved,cancel" widget="statusbar" />
                <button name="submit_modification" string="Submit for manager" type="object" class="btn-primary"
                        attrs="{'invisible': [('state','not in','draft')]}"/>
                <button name="modification_approval" type="object" string="Approve" class="oe_highlight"
                        groups="hr_attendance.group_hr_attendance_manager"
                        attrs="{'invisible': [('state','not in','waiting')]}"/>
                <button name="modification_rejection" type="object" string="Cancel" class="oe_highlight"
                        groups="hr_attendance.group_hr_attendance_manager"
                        attrs="{'invisible': [('state','not in','waiting')]}"/>
            </header>
            <sheet>

                <h2>
                    <group>

                        <field name="employee"/>
                    </group>
                </h2>
                <group string="Morning" col="4" colspan="4">
                    <field name="time_check_in_1"/>
                    <field name="time_check_out_1"/>
                </group>
                <group string="Afternoon" col="4" colspan="4">
                    <field name="time_check_in_2"/>
                    <field name="time_check_out_2"/>
                </group>
                <label for="note"/>
                <field name="note"/>
            </sheet>
            <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers" groups="base.group_user"/>
            <field name="activity_ids" widget="mail_activity"/>
            <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>


        </form>
    </field>
</record>
 <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="attendance_modification_request_form_action">
    <field name="name">Attendance modification Request</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">attendance.modification.request</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="domain">[]</field>
    <field name="context">{"search_default_requested_by":uid}</field>
    <!--            <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_attendance_request_search"/>-->
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
            Click to start a new attendance modification request process.
        </p>
    </field>
</record>
 <menuitem action="attendance_modification_request_form_action" id="menu_attendance_modification_request"
          name="Attendance modification request" parent="hr_attendance.menu_hr_attendance_manage_attendances"
          sequence="14" groups="hr_attendance.group_hr_attendance"/>
 <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_view_attendance_request_approval">
    <field name="name">Attendance modification request to approve</field>
    <field name="res_model">attendance.modification.request</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="domain">[('state','!=','approved'),('state','!=','cancel')]</field>

    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="oe_view_no_content_create">Create new Record
        </p>
    </field>
</record>
 <menuitem action="action_view_attendance_request_approval" id="menu_attendance_modification_request_to_approve"
          name="Attendance modification request to Approve"
          parent="hr_attendance.menu_hr_attendance_manage_attendances"
          sequence="15" groups="hr_attendance.group_hr_attendance_manager"/>
```

Comment: Make sure that your manager has access to the model that action you are passing in menuitem. Means the model which is open open clicking on that menu.

Comment: He has access to the model attendance but my menu display only for the admin user

Comment: Your user have access of parent menu hr_attendance.menu_hr_attendance_manage_attendances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i should add ir.model.access.csv file

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink access_attendance_modification_request,access_attendance_modification_request,model_attendance_modification_request,hr_attendance.group_hr_attendance_manager,1,1,1,1 access_attendance_modification_request,access_attendance_modification_request,model_attendance_modification_request,hr_attendance.group_hr_attendance,1,1,1,1
```